# Using gcc with -g flag before running gdb

Tags: c

without -g flag:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048274
```

with -g flag:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048277: file example.c, line 31.
```

I vaguely know -g option stores the symbol table information.

1. What does the -g option exactly do?
2. Is there any way I can look at this symbol table?

Comment: You can use objdump to see symbols.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-g` (for `gcc`) stores debugging information in the output files so that debuggers can pick it up and present more useful information during the debugging process. Exactly *what* gets stored can depend a great deal on the environment you're running in.

One way to look at what this consists of is to use `objdump` with the `--debugging` option (or its equivalent short form `-g` which matches `gcc`).

Comment: objdump -g example gives example:     file format elf32-i386
objdump: example: no recognized debugging information

Answer (score 1):

The `-g` command line option asks the compiler to emit additional debugging information; on Linux, the format is [DWARF 2](http://dwarfstd.org/), but other platforms may have different defaults -- [stabs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabs) was more common, once upon a time.

`readelf --debug-dump` can be used to dump the debugging information itself if you're curious in what it adds -- you can see the entire program source in the `.debug_info` section, for example.